# How to Merge One Fusion Table data to Another Fusion Table programmatically?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-fusion-tables

Example: I have one Fusion Table with three columns Id, Name and Location. I have another Fusion Table with two columns EmployeeName and EmployeeID.

Once I Merge tables I would like to show total five columns like Id, Name, Location, EmployeeName and EmployeeID.

How can this be done using Javascript or Asp.net or c#?